# Multiple criteria with including 'or' in Javascript if-else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm newbie in Javascript. Trying to write a function in which I will enter value for three items and it will return the total price. If I enter negative value for any parameter than it will give an error message instead of total price.

**Expected results pseudocode:**

if pen < 0 or pencil < 0 or sharpner < 0 then
errorMessage
else
totalPrice

**My code is :**

```
function costCalc (pen, pencil, sharpner){

var penPrice = pen * 10;
var pencilPrice = pencil * 20;
var sharpnerPrice = sharpner * 5;

if (penPrice < 0 || pencilPrice < 0 || sharpnerPrice < 0 ){
    return "Something went wrong."
} else{
    var totalPrice = penPrice + pencilPrice + sharpnerPrice;
    return totalPrice
    }
}
```

I've 'return' twice here. Is this code ok? Or, I've to change something?

Advance thanks for your cooperation.

Regards.

Comment: A function can contain as many `return` statements as you want. There are some coding practices that say that the type of the value returned should be the same (in your case it is string or number), there are also some folks that favor one return per function. However both are a matter of taste.

Comment: Suggestion: validate inputs on the client side. Only accept valid inputs, then you can just concern yourself with summing and returning the price, keeping your function pure and doing one thing. You could also pass all the arguments in as an object (key value pairs) and use the spread syntax to "spread in" all those properties, this way you can keep it scalable and add as many additional prices you need without needing to update your function parameters.

Comment: I'd also look into handling any price adjustments separately in another function that allows you to pass 2 parameters; 1 for item, 1 for multiplier increase. Then return output, add it to object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are doing is fine. The moment you return from a function the remaining code is not executed, the function is "finished". In fact, it is very common to return from a function and intentionally skip the code after the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code but there are alternative ways of implementing it. A few examples, for your reference, could be:

```js
/* 
 * `[item]Price` can be < 0 only if `[item]` < 0 so you can anticipate the check
 * in order to avoid unnecessary calculations
 */

function costCalcB(pen, pencil, sharpner) {
  if (pen < 0 || pencil < 0 || sharpner < 0) {
    return "Something went wrong."
  } else {
    const penPrice = pen * 10;
    const pencilPrice = pencil * 20;
    const sharpnerPrice = sharpner * 5;
    const totalPrice = penPrice + pencilPrice + sharpnerPrice;
    return totalPrice;
  }
}

/*
 * You can also avoid the `else` block
 */
 
 function costCalcC(pen, pencil, sharpner) {
  if (pen < 0 || pencil < 0 || sharpner < 0) {
    return "Something went wrong."
  }
  
  const penPrice = pen * 10;
  const pencilPrice = pencil * 20;
  const sharpnerPrice = sharpner * 5;
  const totalPrice = penPrice + pencilPrice + sharpnerPrice;
  return totalPrice;
}

/*
 * In case of error, you can also throw an exception rather than return
 */
 
 function costCalcD(pen, pencil, sharpner) {
  if (pen < 0 || pencil < 0 || sharpner < 0) {
    throw "Something went wrong."
  }
  
  const penPrice = pen * 10;
  const pencilPrice = pencil * 20;
  const sharpnerPrice = sharpner * 5;
  const totalPrice = penPrice + pencilPrice + sharpnerPrice;
  return totalPrice;
}

try {
    costCalcD(10, 10, -1);
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```